# typescript events for extended classes

Tags: javascript, events, typescript, leaflet

I'm working on a leaflet map using typescript. To add some logic to a custom marker I'm extending the L.Marker class.

```
export class FeatureMarker extends L.Marker {
```

This is working for me, but now I want to add some custom events. I saw some examples online (e.g. http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/611-events-andor-callbacks/), but they require me to extend another class. Which, as far as I understand, is not possible with java/typescript.

So I'm looking for a way to trigger events from within a FeatureMarker instance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but they require me to extend another class. Which, as far as I understand, is not possible with javascript/typescript.

Yes you cannot do multiple inheritance.

> So I'm looking for a way to trigger events from within a FeatureMarker instance.

You can do it with a mixin, Reference: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Mixins%20in%20TypeScript

Alternatively (and better IMHO) just use composition:

```
export class FeatureMarker extends L.Marker {
      emitter : EventObj  = new EventObj();
```